# Spring @Value not able to get value from YAML

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I have the follow YAML file

```
git.username: myusername
git.password: mypassword
```

And in my Java Source file, I have the following annotation

```
@Value("${git.username}")
private String username;
@Value("${git.password}")
private String password;
```

Everything works fine till this point. However, it is not able to retrieve the value when I changed the format of the YAML to the following.

```
git:
  username: myusername
  password: mypassword
```

How should I reference the yaml value in this format? `@Value(???)`

Comment: look here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml

Comment: Where is your yaml file located? Is any other property working or just git ones don't? What type of indentation are you using?

Comment: The linked duplicate provides many suggestions, i.e. indentation, duplicate keys, etc. Your attempt looks broadly correct, you shouldn't have to change the annotation

Comment: @tec I have not tried the rest, but just the git one is not working. I mean it works in the old format, just not in the new format which puzzles me.

Comment: @Michael that means it is possibly the indentation?